# can interprete the markdown values in the input fied itsef onBlur() if yes then how?

Tags: reactjs, input, frontend, markdown

I want to create a input field in react which can react the markdown from user and convert it in the same input field once user losses focus.

I tried using the react-markdown library but in that i have to show the preview in another  rather then showing in the same input field.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import ReactMarkdown from "react-markdown";
import HTMLInput from "./HtmlInput";

export default function App() {
  const [input, setInput] = useState("");
  const [input2, setInput2] = useState("");
  const markdown = `
  # Header 1
  ## Header 2

  _ italic _

  ** bold **

  <b> bold Html </b>
  `;

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <textarea
        autoFocus
        // dangerouslySetInnerHTML={<ReactMarkdown source={input} />}
        value={input}
        onChange={(e) => setInput(e.target.value)}
      />
      <ReactMarkdown
        source={input}
        onChange={(e) => console.log(e.target.value)}
      />

      {/* <HTMLInput /> */}
    </div>
  );
}
```

I also tried converting the input markdown to a html tag and seting it to the value of the input field but i cant interpret the html tag in the input field.